# In column dataframe, how do I find the date just before a given date

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF :

```
Date
01/07/2022
10/07/2022
20/07/2022
```

The date x is

```
12/07/2022
```

So basically the function should return

```
10/07/2022
```

I am trying to avoid looping over the whole column but I don't know how to specify that I want the max date before a given date.

```
max(DF['Dates']) #Returns 20/07/2022
```

Comment: `max` takes in a second argument called `key`. But that won't prevent looping over the entire collection.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Does it means that there is no way to use `Where` ect ?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Date'] < pd.to_datetime('12/07/2022', dayfirst=True), 'Date'].max()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = '12/07/2022'
f = '%d/%m/%Y'

(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format=f)
.where(lambda x: x.lt(pd.to_datetime(d,format=f)))
.max())
```

Comment: the format might not be necessary if you use dayfirst=True parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can filter dates by index:

```
df[df.Date < pd.to_datetime('12/07/2022')]
```

Then find max:

```
max(df[df.Date < pd.to_datetime('12/07/2022')].Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Setting some stuff up
Date = ["01/07/2022", "10/07/2022", "20/07/2022"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":Date})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
target_date = pd.to_datetime("12/07/2022", format='%d/%m/%Y')



df = df.sort_values(by=["Date"]) # Sort by date
# Find all dates that are before target date, then choose the last one (i.e. the most recent one)
df.Date[df.Date < target_date][-1:].dt.date.values[0]
```

Output:

```py
datetime.date(2022, 7, 10)
```